# StreamBuilder: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Stream' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder, flutter-http

I'm using a StreamBuilder widget to show the score in real-time (fetching the data from API and then passing it to the stream) but while doing this process, it is throwing up the following error

"A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Stream' doesn't allow null"

Here is the Code

```
class Match extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<Match> createState() => _MatchState();
}

class _MatchState extends State<Match> {
  
    getCricketScoreApi() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(api_url);
    var response = await get(url);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      final score = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return  score['cricket_score'];
    } else {
      return print('Something went wrong');
    }
  }

  Stream streamScore() { 
    return Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer) => getCricketScoreApi()); // Calling method after every 1 second
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: streamScore(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
              var cricket_score_api = snapshot.data.toString();
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return Center(
                  child: Text(cricket_score_api, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 25.0)), // Error: Instance of Future
                );
              } else {
                return Text('Null');
              }
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out, I forgot to return it but the score is still not appearing up in the widget. It is throwing up the following error on the screen "Instance of 'Future"

Comment: what about your json response?

Comment: This score['cricket_score'] returns the cricket score. I'm trying to print it on the Text widget but currently, it is showing up the following error Instance of 'Future @JahidulIslam

Comment: please share your updated code after return and try with remove `Future` from `getCricketScoreApi()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you say, the original error came from not returning a value.

The current error is even simpler, you ARE returning a value, but that value is, an instance of `Future`, so when you call `snapshot.data.toString();`, you get the literal text `instance of Future`

I came up with two ways of fixing the issue, here they are now:

#### 1. Make your stream function an async* function:

```
Stream streamScore() async* {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield await getCricketScoreApi();
  }
}
```

`async*` functions work like `async` functions, but instead of returning a future, they return a stream immediately and add values to the stream progressively using the `yield` keyword.

The one thing I don't love about the approach above is the usage of `while (true)`, it seems unsafe.

#### 2. Deal with the future

```
Stream<Future> streamScore() {
  ...
}
...
body: StreamBuilder<Future>(
    stream: streamScore(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          return FutureBuilder(
            future: snapshot.data!
            builder: (context, snapshot1) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(child: Text(snapshot1.data!.toString()));
              } 
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          );
        } else {
          return Text('Null');
        }
    }
),
```

Hopefully one of the above solutions fix the new issue?

Comment: The first one worked for me! Thank you so much! Appreciate it

Comment: One question, though! As you know, In this method, I'm hitting an API after every one second to check the score, if it would be a paid API, I would have exceeded the API requests very shortly. Is there any other better way to do it? @h8moss

Comment: Sorry, to be honest I don't know that much about API connection, although I will say that for most use cases, updating the data every second is not necessary, you could update over longer periods of time and give the user the option of updating manually as well? Also maybe check the docs of the API if you have any, maybe there is a way to request more up to date data without making a whole new request? I'm just spitballing tho.

Comment: No problem! As I said this would show the score of cricket, so people would be watching the screen constantly (such things should be shown in real-time)